# C++ - Understanding References and Memory Addresses

Tags: c++, memory, reference

I have read some of the technical differences between references and memory addresses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c), however I am trying to find a more abstract way to understand them. Consider the code:

```
char foo = 'a';
char& bar = foo;
char& bar2 = *(char*)(&foo);
cout << bar << endl;
cout << bar2 << endl;
```

The output in both cases is 'a'. Is it then correct to conclude from this that a reference (bar2) is simply a memory address (&foo) with an associated type (char)? Or does this explanation fall apart?

Comment: `*(char*)(&foo)`: This is the same as `foo`.

Comment: Do you mean pointers and references?

Comment: Once you understand that `char foo; char &bar = foo;` and `char bar; char &foo = bar;` are exactly identical , you will understand what references are :)  (well, lvalue references anyway).

Comment: In C++ you can pass an Object by reference or by value. When you use a pointer in C++ such as: int *x = 100; x is a variable that points to a memory address/location eg: 650, where it points to the value 100. Where as: int &y = x; y is a variable that makes a reference to the value of x, it also points to the same memory address 650. Now if you change the value of x say: x = 450; then you have also change the value of y. y is just a reference to x in this case and memory address is 650. In C++ "&" or a reference to, is mostly used with input parameters such as constructor and functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bar2` is identical to `bar`, since `*(char*)(&foo)` (value at the address of `foo`, interpreted as `char`) is the same as `foo` itself.

The important thing to understand here, is that a reference is basically a pointer that is automatically dereferenced, and whose address cannot be changed. Or, in other words, an alias for a variable or memory location.

Consider this:

```
char *c = new char('x');
char &ref = *c;
ref = 'y';
assert(*c == 'y'); //the memory at c was changed through ref
assert(&ref == c); //the address of ref is the same as c, because ref is an alias for the memory at c

char c2 = 'x';
char &ref2 = c2;
char *p = &c2;
c2 = 'y';
assert(p == &ref2);
assert(ref2 == 'y' && *p == 'y');
```

Answer (score 5):

The most succinct definition of a `reference` in C++ is that:

> It declares a named variable as a reference, that is, an alias to an already-existing object or function.

1. Its value is the same as the object it is an alias of.
2. Its address (obtained by the `&` operator) is the same as the address of the object it is an alias of.

Answer (score 3):

Any time you have a *value* (i.e. an object that is the result of evaluating an expression) in C++, you can bind that value to a reference variable. Evaluating the reference later results in an lvalue that is precisely the object which was bound to the reference. For example:

```
int a = 10;
a;             // the value of the expression is immediately discarded
int & r = a;   // this time the value is bound to a reference variable
r;             // this is the same value as a
r = 20;
```

Evaluating both `a` and `r` produces an lvalue of type `int`, which is the variable `a`.

Another example:

```
Foo f();

f();            // a discarded prvalue of type Foo
Foo && r = f(); // this time the value of f() is bound to r
r.do_stuff();
```

This time, each evaluation of `f()` produces a distinct value of type `Foo` (a "temporary object"). The first one is immediately discarded; the second one is bound to the reference `r`. Evaluating `r` produces an lvalue of type `Foo`, namely the temporary object returned from the second function call.

Comment: This seems to disagree with the distinction between *object* and *value*, where an *object* stores or contains a *value*.

Comment: @dyp: I think that got clarified in C++14, which uses the term "temporary object" consistently. So once you bind a value to a reference, you can observe the object.

Comment: I know that there's been a defect report (which I cannot find unfortunately) about "temporary" vs "temporary object", but I'm unaware of any such dramatic change in terminology. An object can contain a value; you can change the value it contains. I do not think that binding a value to a reference makes much sense, especially since you can modify something bound to a non-const ref. As far as I know, you always bind an object to a reference, that object might be constructed *from* a value.

Comment: This answer feels either wrong or confusing. If *value* is in fact the right term from the standard than I think that needs some explaining. To me value is something like 10. So It sounds like you're saying 10 is bound to `r` which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Oh great. The Standard and even the latest github draft is inconsistent :( [dcl.init.ref]/1 seems to disallow initializing a reference from a value, it requires an object or function. Later it uses "value of the initializer expression", which sounds odd as well.

Comment: Found the DR/resolution: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3918.html

Comment: @dyp: Yep, indeed :-)

Comment: @PeterSW: `10` is a literal. Evaluating a literal produces a suitable prvalue, and *that* value is bound to the reference when you say `int && r = 10;`. Maybe you are thinking of "value" in the sense of "equivalence class of objects that compare equal".

Comment: The Standard contains such confusing statements as "The value of a literal such as `12`, `7.3e5` or `true` is also a prvalue." (which suggests that a value is an expression) Anyway, for `int && r = 10;`, the bullet point [dcl.init.ref]/5.2.2.2 applies (yay numbered bullet points!) which says that *a temporary is created* which is copy-initialized from the initializer expression. So the *value* is not bound directly. (I think it should be *a temporary object*, btw)

Comment: @dyp: I'm using the word "value" in the sense of "value of an expression", which can be, say, an lvalue, which *is* the object. In that sense to different integer variables may be equal but are distinct values, in the sense that they can be separately addressed and modified. I agree though that the terminology is confusing.

Comment: @PeterSW: I reworded it a bit. The terminology is confusing, agreed. I use "value" in the sense of the value categories, i.e. things produced by evaluating expressions.